# iPad displays as charging but is not plugged in

Tags: ios, ipad, network, battery

My iPad was charging and I wanted to go and check my Instagram. So I unplugged my charger and went into Instagram, but it would not load so I closed it and then I looked at my battery bar and it said it was charging. However, it wasn't plugged in. I tried rebooting but it would not let me.

The next morning I checked the iPad and while it was unplugged it said it was charging at 69% just like last night.

What might be wrong if I cannot access any apps requiring Wi-Fi but other offline games and apps work?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have some hardware problems there. Which ipad is this?

From the sound of it, you have some pins bridged on the ipad, or it has liquid damage or something like that. Something like that is hard to diagnose without physically seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with my ipad. Restart your iPad in the settings it will eventually die from trying to restart and when you plug it in to charge it will work fine after it charges again.